# How to avoid text blocks and or div from overlapping each other as I map through array of data

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve a similar look to this https://api.nasa.gov/assets/img/general/insight_photo.png, but my text blocks are all simply overlapping each other in one spot rather than being side by side, with some space in between just as my example image shows. Still new-ish to this stuff so maybe I'm overlooking something. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```js
const arr = _.map(weather, (value, key) => ({
  key,
  ...value,
}));

console.log(arr.slice(0, 7));

return (
  <div className="container" style={{position: 'relative'}}>
    Insight: Mars Weather Service
    <img src={land} alt="" style={{height: '400px', width: '100%'}} />
    {arr.slice(0, 7).map((weather) => (
      <div
        class="text-block"
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: '20px',
          right: '20px',
          backgroundColor: 'black',
          color: 'white',
          paddingLeft: '20px',
          paddingRight: '20px',
        }}
      >
        <h3>Sol {weather.key}</h3>
        <h5>High: {weather.AT.av}F</h5>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
};
```

Comment: You need to shift the style position in the map function.  something like `right: (20 * i)+'px'`

Comment: You're giving each item a position absolute with the same bottom and right so they'll be on the same position. You'd need to change the right after each item if you still want to use position absolute, but probably you can achieve the same layout with something more flexible.

Comment: Agreed.  You could just wrap them all in a horizontal div and have them position themselves with relatively simple CSS.  A few simple css rules on the .container div would do it.